# Problema en insert SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Tengo un proyecto en android, en el cual debo insertar registros en un activity y mostrarlos en un recycler, al realizar el insert se muestra el mensaje de que se inserto correctamente, esos datos los debo mostrar en un segundo activity, al hacer la consulta si encuentra los datos pero me los trae nulos y por lo tanto muestra los campos vacíos. Aquí dejo el código.

ActivityInsertar

```html
llenardatos(){
conexion con;
con=new conexion(this);
con.open();
SQLiteDatabase bd = con.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
 
registro.put(utilidades.Titulo, _titulo.getText().toString());
registro.put(utilidades.Nombre, Nombre.getText().toString());
registro.put(utilidades.telefono, _telefono.getText().toString());
   registro.put(utilidades.User_Add, idUser);
bd.insertOrThrow(utilidades.TablaPersonas, null, registro);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registro agregado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

onAgregarSuccess();
}

onAgregarSuccess(){
_btnAgregar.setEnabled(true);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMostrar.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

ActivityMostrar

```html
public boolean GetListGestiones() {
try {

tring query = "Select * from " + utilidades.TablaPersonas+ " where User_Add= '" + idUser +"'";
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
Toast.makeText(context, "No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

else if (cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
do {
entidades=new Entidades(entidades);    
entidades.setTitulo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(utilidades.Titulo)));
entidades.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(utilidades.Nombre)));
entidades.setTelefono(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(utilidades.Telefono)));       
listtablapersonas.add(entidades);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.toString();
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun lo comentado al parecer no se insertan los registros de forma correcta.

Te detallo un ejemplo para realizar un insert y luego un Select.
Primero insertamos los registros ,en mi ejemplo tengo los valores en un Array lo cual recorro con un for.

```
private void CargarIngresos(){
        Long filasInsertadas=Long.parseLong("0");
        try {
            AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
            SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

            ArrayList<String> lista=Genericos.CategoriasIngresos();
            System.out.println("Mylog :"+"lista tamaño"+lista.size()+"\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size() ; i++){

                registro.put("descrip",lista.get(i) );
                registro.put("tipo","ingresos");
                registro.put("pacht_logo","logo"+i+1);

                System.out.println("Mylog :"+"Descr:"+lista.get(i)+"\n");
                System.out.println("Mylog :"+"tipo:ingresos"+"\n");

                filasInsertadas= filasInsertadas + bd.insert("categorias",null ,registro);

            }
            bd.close();

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            System.out.print("Error al insertar en BD categorias ingresos:"+e.getMessage());

        }

        System.out.println("Mylog :"+"FilasInsertadas"+filasInsertadas+"\n");
        if(filasInsertadas > 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registros Insertados Correctamente!"+filasInsertadas, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Luego realizamos el select con este metodo.

```
 private void Select(){
    try{
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper ingresarbd = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = ingresarbd.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM categorias ", null);
        if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
            do{


                /*
                obtenemos los valores de cada columna con su respectivo index
                Ejemplo mi tabla es asi.
                CREATE TABLE categorias (" +
                "id_categoria INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
                "descrip text ," +
                "tipo text ,"+
                "pacht_logo text "+
                ")"
                En donde id_categoria seria el 0
                descrip seria 1
                tipo seria 2
                pacht_logo seria 3
                 */
                Categorias cate=new Categorias();
                cate.setCode(String.valueOf(fila.getString(0)));
                cate.setDescripcion(fila.getString(1));
                cate.setTipo(fila.getString(2));


                System.out.println("tCodigo:"+fila.getString(0));
                System.out.println("tDescripcion :"+fila.getString(1));
                System.out.println("tTipo:"+fila.getString(2));
                System.out.println("tlogo:"+fila.getString(3));

                Lista_adapter.add(cate);
            } while(fila.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        System.out.print("Error al obtener tablas de BD categorias:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, he probado tu codigo y no me ha funcionado, no lo comprendo :c

Comment: Utilizando  System.out.println("Titulo:"+cursor.getColumnIndex("Titulo")); tienes algo en la consola? Deberia de mostrar un resultado?

Comment: me lo muestra: null  :C

Comment: Edito mi Respuesta,Tambien me puedes escribir a mi correo:cjsemilio@gmail.com